# Python - bypass Malwarebytes blocked websites with urllib?

Tags: python, block, urllib

Here's a part my code that gets source code from websites:

```
#Header dictionary
headers = {}
#Header for websites
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"

#Urllib code
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
```

This works, however my Malwarebytes blocks some websites even when I use this program. Is there a way I can bypass this block?

I want to get the source code and possibly write it to a txt file, all without Malwarebytes blocking anything but **avoiding malicious stuff**.

Comment: You should ask yourself why you want to access websites that are blocked by an anti-malware program.

Comment: If your antimalware program is giving you trouble then disable it.

Comment: @AndréDaniel that's possibly a very bad advice

Comment: @yuvi I don't see why it is, as the antimalware probably flagged the domain/URL as malicious because it either has exploits against browsers or just hosts malware files, none of which would work against this Python script;

Comment: @AndréDaniel without sufficient information about the url OP is using, to what domain it's reaching, or what the rest of the script is doing with it (because this is very obviously an excerpt), you can't know that for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A third party program (Malwarebytes) is controlling network traffic from and to your computer. You are at the mercy of this software.

Unless this program provides a method to bypass its checks (which I highly doubt) the advice is that

- Disable Malwarebytes
- Run your Python script on a different computer
- Contact Malwarebytes how to adjust their program to allow your script (highly unlikely they have any bypass mechanism or they will do any exception for single individual)

Also as a further security advise I suggest you run and visit malware sites in a browser run inside a Linux virtual machine.

Comment: Your doubt regarding bypass/[whitelisting](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/164263-need-help-removing-edeal-by-ad-malware/?hl=whitelist#entry935305) is unjustified and your answer poorly addresses what the OP needs based on the level of his question. Most of the comments on the OP agree.

Answer (score 2):

If you really trust the url you're trying to reach, and have no problem that your script will reach it and interact with it (because, you should seriously consider that maybe malewarebytes is actually doing it's job), you can add the requested IP to the "Web Exclusion" list. Just follow [these instructions](https://helpdesk.malwarebytes.org/hc/en-us/articles/201948297-How-do-I-stop-Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware-from-blocking-a-website-or-network-program-that-I-trust-) or open **malewarebytes > settings > Web Exclusions** and just logic your way (it's pretty straightforward).

Now, you've asked:

> I want to [...] all without Malwarebytes blocking anything but **avoiding
>   malicious stuff**.

See, this is **impossible**. Either you trust malewarebytes to decide what's malicious and what's not, *or* you decide that yourself. You can't have it both ways - because there aren't both ways here. MB is supposed to block only malicious things, and if it gives out false positives, **the only one who can tell the computer to ignore those is you**, and again, when you do that, you run it at your **own risk**.